# How Microsoft applies versioning for nuget packages

Tags: .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, versioning, semantic-versioning

I have tried to find out how Microsoft applies versioning in their NuGet packages (i.e. https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json) but there are a couple of numbers I can't figure out where they come from.

If we take these packages from `System.Text.Json` for instance:

```
5.0.0-rc.2.20475.5
5.0.0-rc.1.20451.14
5.0.0-preview.8.20407.11
5.0.0-preview.1.20120.5
4.7.0-preview3.19551.4
4.6.0-preview9.19421.4
```

I can't figure out the logic behind the two last numbers. The second to last seems to be always increasing even when changing Major or Minor versions but I don't know when it is increased.
And the last number seems to be reset every time the second to last is increased, but again I can't figure out the logic behind it.

Does anyone have any information about it?

Comment: You may look at this article [Version vs VersionSuffix vs PackageVersion: What do they all mean?](https://andrewlock.net/version-vs-versionsuffix-vs-packageversion-what-do-they-all-mean/)

Comment: You should have a look at [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning).

Comment: Thanks for both links. They are quite informative, but still they don't say anything how Microsoft actually applies it.